# Struct tm time inside of another struct

Tags: c

As part of my assignment, I have been asked to construct a structure of command, which stores a list of executed commands. The instructions provided were:

```
typedef struct {
char *name;
struct tm time;
int code;
} Command;
Note: struct tm defined in <time.h>
```

I am having trouble accessing the time values stored in the `struct tm time`, which is stored inside of my `Command` structure.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct command{
    char* name;
    struct tm *time;
    int code;
} Command;

void add_log(Command command[], int return_code, char name[100]){
    
    time_t current_time;
    time(&current_time);

    command[0].code = return_code;
    command[0].name = strdup(name);
    command[0].time = localtime(&current_time);
}

int main(){

    Command command[10];

    add_log(command, 0, "log");

    printf("Printing return code\n%d\n", command[0].code);
    printf("Printing command name\n%s\n", command[0].name);

    char time_log[10];

    if (strftime(time_log, 10, "%c", time)){
        printf("\nPrinting time log\n");
        puts(time_log);
    }
    else{
        printf("FAILED");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting looks as follows:

```
tester.c: In function ‘main’:
tester.c:37:38: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘strftime’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   37 |     if (strftime(time_log, 10, "%c", time)){
      |                                      ^~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      time_t (*)(time_t *) {aka long int (*)(long int *)}
In file included from tester.c:8:
/usr/include/time.h:90:32: note: expected ‘const struct tm * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘time_t (*)(time_t *)’ {aka ‘long int (*)(long int *)’}
   90 |    const struct tm *__restrict __tp) __THROW;
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
Printing return code
0
Printing command name
log
FAILED
```

I am specifically focusing on the line  `note: expected ‘const struct tm * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘time_t (*)(time_t *)’ {aka ‘long int (*)(long int *)’}`. If the fourth argument for the `strftime` is wrong in my case, could anyone please point out what the correct argument should be?

Comment: If you're only ever referencing `command[0]` then perhaps your argument should just be `Command* command` and internally `command->code` instead.

Comment: Tip: In C don't try and pin down array argument sizes. Use `char*` instead of `char[N]`.

Comment: There is no `time` variable in the `main` function. The `time` being passed to `strftime` is probably the `time` function from `<time.h>`

Comment: `time()` is a function. You should probably use another name for that variable. Maybe you mean `command[0].time`?

Comment: You probably meant to do: `strftime(time_log, 10, "%c", command[0].time)`

Comment: **WARNING**: `localtime()` returns a very short-lived value. As per [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime): "The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions." If you want to retain a copy, consider calling `strdup()` on it immediately after receiving the response.

Comment: You didn't follow the instructions -- which were `struct tm time;` whereas you have written `struct tm *time;`

Comment: Thanks for the great advice @tadman, and @kaylum! I was not able to get it to work, but I think I found a workaround by calling the following in my main function: ```printf("Printing time\n%s\n", asctime(&command[0].my_time));```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
strftime(time_log, 10, "%c", time)
```

You need to access the time object in command so you should be doing

```
strftime(time_log, 10, "%c", command->time)
```

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem:

OP's code `command[0].time = localtime(&current_time);` attempts

```
// Pseudo code
struct tm = *struct tm
```

Instead

```
struct tm * lt = localtime(&current_time);
if (lt != NULL) {
  command[0].time = *lt;
} else {
  // Handle conversion error;
}
```